# How do I keep agendas.org TODOS out of agenda view?

Tags: org-mode

When I press C-a t to create my list of TODO items, all of my TODOS on agendas.org file get imported into the list. Also, a lot of the items look really old, and some of them I've completed. Can I safely delete the agendas.org file? If it is part of the Mobile Org, that's not a problem because I'm not using that anymore anyway. I just am having trouble finding/reading documentation on it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the documentation. You according to the info page for MobileOrg (Node *B.2 Pushing to Mobile Org* in my current version), pushing in MobileOrg creates the agendas.org file. I think my problem is that I set my staging area to be inside my org folder, and I have Org Mode search for all .org files for agenda views. I just deleted the file and changed my staging area and that fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, I was having the same problem (also setting my staging area inside org folder). Now  MobileOrg is working as expected.